# Symfony 4.x route annotations not working on homestead

Tags: routes, annotations, symfony4, php-7, homestead

On Windows, when I install a clean symfony project with

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton my-project
```

and set a Route like

```
/**
 * @Route("/login", name="login")
 */
```

and then start the symfony dev server, everything works just fine.

If I try to run the same environment on a homestead vagrant box, then the annotations get ignored. bin/console debug:router shows no routes either.

If I define them in the routes.yaml though they work. What am I missing?

I have tried with homestead 8.5.3 and with 8.4.0.

My homestead.yaml is like:

```
ip: 192.168.10.10
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox
authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa
folders:
    -
        map: '/path/to/code'
        to: /home/vagrant/code
sites:
    -
        map: homestead.test
        to: /home/vagrant/code/public
        type: symfony4
databases:
    - homestead
name: my_project
hostname: my_project
```

I have a feeling that it has to do with the shared folders. Have you ever experienced such a behavior?

Comment: I also have this exact issue with Laravel 8.4.0 and a very barebones project. Another issue I'm having is after adding the profiler-pack it does not show up on the default page. Not sure if that's because it is the default page or if there is an issue with adding new packages in general.

Comment: @Brooks I tested a lemp box, that works just fine. It seems to be some kind if config issue in homestead

Comment: by any chance do you have a non-standard `/vendor` location?

Comment: No, I don't. Do you have sporadic errors about container files that coudln't be deleted?

Comment: I do not. If this doesn't get some attention on here this should probably go into an issue on the homestead GitHub.

Comment: I threw this in a GitHub issue: https://github.com/laravel/homestead/issues/1179

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem about two weeks. I looked for solutions that I did not find. After having on the vagrant documentation, the part concerning the system `nfs` and understand how it works. I managed to solve the problem.
First of all have to install the plugin on vagrant. source git https://github.com/winnfsd/vagrant-winnfsd. Via the following command

> `vagrant plugin install vagrant-winnfsd`

After installing the plugin, in your file `homestead.yaml`, add this line in the `folders` section

> `type: "nfs"`

In your case, just after `to: /home/vagrant/code`

Comment: i don't see the relation ? i tested what did you said , but it doesn't work